# How to get wave file properties using Python3 on Win32 environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1st I tried this:

```
import wave

#read wave file I'm trying to open
def getWaveInfo():
    try:
        #get the list of wave file attributes im interested in (channels, famerate, frames number...)
        w = wave.open('wave.wav','rb')
        print("Number of channels is: ",    w.getnchannels())
        print("Sample width in bytes is: ", w.getsampwidth())
        print("Framerate is: ",             w.getframerate())
        print("Number of frames is: ",      w.getnframes())
    except:
        print(wave.error)
```

Still got nothing. Then I changed into this:

```
import wave

#read wave file I'm trying to open
def getWaveInfo():
    #get the list of wave file attributes im interested in (channels, famerate, frames number...)
    w = wave.open('wave.wav','rb')
    print("Number of channels is: ",    w.getnchannels())
    print("Sample width in bytes is: ", w.getsampwidth())
    print("Framerate is: ",             w.getframerate())
    print("Number of frames is: ",      w.getnframes())

if __main__ == '__main__':
    getWaveInfo()
```

Still nothing happens! I even used the C:\python wave.py > test.txt and the file is blank!

All the code above is commented already. Any insights anyone on why this is not working?
I'm using Windows 7 and Wing IDE 101 V5. Python 3.3.2

I don't know what else to do to make it work... already debugged in Wings IDE and after the wave import nothing else works.

Now my source code is like this:

```
import wave

def getWaveInfo():
    try:
        w = wave.open('audio.wav','rb')
        print("Number of channels is: ",    w.getnchannels())
        print("Sample width in bytes is: ", w.getsampwidth())
        print("Framerate is: ",             w.getframerate())
        print("Number of frames is: ",      w.getnframes())
    except:
        print(w.error)
```

And I finally have raised an error(!):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\audio.py", line 1, in <module>
builtins.ImportError: bad magic number in 'wave': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

My python filename was `"wave.py"` but now I changed it to `"audio.py"`.
Also changed the audio wave file from `"wave.wav"` to `"audio.wav"`

Changed my code a little bit more and now its like this:

```
from wave import *

def getWaveInfo():
     w = wave.open('audio.wav','rb')
     print("Number of channels is: ",    w.getnchannels())
     print("Sample width in bytes is: ", w.getsampwidth())
     print("Framerate is: ",             w.getframerate())
     print("Number of frames is: ",      w.getnframes())

if __name__ == "__main__":
     getWaveInfo()
```

Now I have the error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 4, in getWaveInfo
    #print 'Exiting sandbox process'
builtins.NameError: global name 'wave' is not defined`
```

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get? And which `wave` library are you using?

Comment: I'm running this code from my C:\ drive and with the wave file in the same level of hierarchy of this code. Of this py file. Which is wave.py. Nothing happens! Wing doesn't even blink! Only think I get in Wing IDE python shell is: "[evaluate wave.py]"

Did my best and got all codes and examples from documentation:
http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/wave.html?highlight=wave#module-wave

Comment: Try replacing `wave.error` with `print(wave.error)` so that you actually see the error. Or just completely remove the `try` block for now.

Comment: I don't get it... removed the "try:...except:" block.. nothing. Put a printf() function statement in the exception of the try except(before removing it, of course) and also nothing happened. Lemme try to run this in the prompt.

Comment: I tried in the prompt using the following command:
"C:\>python wave.py > test.txt"
And it generated a txt file... but it's blank! Oh my... what am I missing here?

Comment: When I debug in Wing IDE it only goes to the 1st line. It has some errors with the 1st line! How can that be? Am I importing the wave module incorrectly?

Comment: Do you actually *execute* your `getWaveInfo` function? I.e. by calling `getWaveInfo()` somewhere below?

Comment: No. The code I run is the same as stated in the beginning of this post.

Comment: I added the `if __main__ == '__main__':
    getWaveInfo()` but still not working... almost giving up...

Comment: It’s `if __name__ == '__main__'`, not `__main__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: I did it.. same output. :-(

Comment: Please update the question with the current code you are trying.

Comment: Try to remove wave.pyc file from your directory (if you have them).

Comment: @Pawelmhm Oh! I did had a `wave.pyc` file in the same dir. Thanks. I removed it and... now I don't get any error. Back to start.

Comment: So you don't get any errors and no output as well? Remove those try, except blocks, you need to know your errors to deal with them, try-except hides errors from you so you don't know that is wrong.

Comment: @Pawelmhm Thanks! I did something stupid. Sorry bout that. Only now I was able to realize I did `if __main__ == '__main__':` instead of the correct statement which is `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Now I got the error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 4, in getWaveInfo
    #print 'Exiting sandbox process'
builtins.NameError: global name 'wave' is not defined`

Comment: To match your code, you should do `import wave` rather than `from wave import *`

Answer (score 1):

If the file with python script is called wave.py (as you say in comments), just like the module, you're actually importing your own file and not the module. Change your python's file name and see if it works. Example

```
>>> import wave
>>> wave.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/wave.py' #correct filename, wave from python library
>>> quit()
pawel@pawel-VPCEH390X:~/stack$ touch wave.py # create wave file
pawel@pawel-VPCEH390X:~/stack$ python
>>> import wave
>>> wave.__file__
'wave.py' #this is wave file that I already created, no python wave module here
```

Comment: Now tat I changed my code to
`import wave  
  
def getWaveInfo():  
    try:
        w = wave.open('audio.wav','rb')
        print("Number of channels is: ",    w.getnchannels())
        print("Sample width in bytes is: ", w.getsampwidth())
        print("Framerate is: ",             w.getframerate())
        print("Number of frames is: ",      w.getnframes())
    except:
        print(w.error)`

I get the following error:
[evaluate audio.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\audio.py", line 1, in <module>
builtins.ImportError: bad magic number in 'wave': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Comment: I think so. Just try renaming your python file, maybe it will work.

Comment: I'm using Python v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43 BTW. Feeling like loser... trying to make suych a simple thing and it does not work...

Comment: Ok, so now you solved one problem, you renamed your file, that's ok. So you need to solve this new error, maybe you could update your original post or ask new question and post whole stack trace? Don't get discouraged, it's just programming, everyone has to deal with bugs and errors.